# Given a CRS stored matrix A, provide an algorithm for calculating vector u.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, algorithms, numerical-linear-algebra, sparse-matrices

Given an $NxN$ matrix $A$ and vectors $u,v,b$ such that:
$$u_i = {\frac1{a_{ii}}}(b_i - \sum_{j=1,j\neq{i}}^n a_{ij}v_i)$$

And considering $A$ is stored using CRS, provide an algorithm (or pseudocode) for calculating $u$.

---

I am struggling with understanding the above problem and the relation between [CRS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix#Compressed_row_Storage_.28CRS_or_CSR.29) (Compressed Row Storage) and the presented formula. Looking around for resources, I found a somewhat similar formula used in the Gauss–Seidel method, however I am not familiar with it and I'm not sure if it has anything to do with the above problem. I am assuming that the algorithm should be iterative.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: What does CRS mean?

Comment: @copper.hat, Compressed Row Storage (CRS) is a method for storing sparse matrices. I have edited my question with a reference link to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix#Compressed_row_Storage_.28CRS_or_CSR.29

Comment: Do you know how to compute a matrix-vector product with a sparse matrix in this format? I cannot see much difference except with some "special" treatment of diagonal entries. In particular, I do not understand the comment about an iterative solution; this formula is very explicit.